# Prolog, display list result, after algorithm

Tags: recursion, prolog

I got a list of names, and according to whom owns what, I want to split it in 2 different list. I debugged my code and it seems to work, but the console is always returning true, true true...

Expected result: LA = [jean, julie, marc], LB = [jean, julie].
I'd guess my stopped condition is not working correctly, but i'm not sure why.

variables are basically : Head-Now(HN), Rest-Now(RN), List-Automobile(LA), List-Bicycle(LB)

```
owns(julie, car, red).
owns(jean, car, red).
owns(jean, car, green).
owns(marc, car, red).
owns(jean, bicycle, blue).
owns(nathalie, car, black).
owns(julie, bicycle, white).
owns(benjo, car, white).

%divide list of names into list of names owning car, and another list owning bicycle
% What to ask in console : setProp([jean, julie, arthur, marc], LA, LB).
setProp([], LA, LB).
setProp([HN|RN], LA, LB):- owns(HN,car,_), owns(HN,bicycle,_), setProp(RN, [HN|LA], [HN|LB]).
setProp([HN|RN], LA, LB):- owns(HN,car,_),  setProp(RN, [HN|LA], LB).
setProp([HN|RN], LA, LB):- owns(HN,bicycle,_), setProp(RN, LA,[HN|LB]).
setProp([HN|RN], LA, LB):- setProp(RN, LA,LB).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your rules "backwards". The correct form is the one below:

```
setProp([], [], []).
setProp([HN|RN], [HN|LA], [HN|LB]):- owns(HN,car,_), owns(HN,bicycle,_), setProp(RN, LA, LB).
setProp([HN|RN], [HN|LA], LB):- owns(HN,car,_),  setProp(RN, LA, LB).
setProp([HN|RN], LA, [HN|LB]):- owns(HN,bicycle,_), setProp(RN, LA, LB).
setProp([_|RN], LA, LB):- setProp(RN, LA,LB).
```

This set of rules gives you the expected answer.